# WPF : How to do data validation in combobox selectedvalue by dependecy property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I want to do data validation on combo-box selected value. it's default value is 0 so i want it should be selected with any value not 0.

I have binded it's selected value with int dependency property in view model.
i know we can do data validation by dependency property so any help much appreciated.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" Width="100" Margin="10,0,20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TotalPeople}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedPeopleNumber}"    Height="20"/>
```

here is viewmodel dependency property code.

```
public ExpenseViewModel()
{
  totalPeople = new List<int>();
  populate();
}

private void populate()
{
   totalPeople.Add(2);
   totalPeople.Add(3);
   totalPeople.Add(4);
   totalPeople.Add(5);
}
private List<int> totalPeople;
public List<int> TotalPeople
{
      get { return totalPeople; }
      set
      {
            if (totalPeople != value)
            {
                totalPeople = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalPeople");
            }
      }
}
public int SelectedPeopleNumber
{
     get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedPeopleNumberProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SelectedPeopleNumberProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedPeopleNumber.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPeopleNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPeopleNumber", typeof(int), typeof(ExpenseViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

i want combobox should be red bordered when default value is 0.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have got confused between `DependencyProperty` and Databinding `Property`.

Databinding property are the ones which has source items used for displaying the data in the controls and also to store the selected values.

DependencyProperty(DP) are the ones to which you bind the above databinding properties.

In your Xaml Code `SelectedItem` is a DP and you have bound it to another DP(SelectedPeopleNumber) which I guess you did not intend to do.

Below is the fixed code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBox" Width="100" Margin="10,0,20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TotalPeople}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding  Path=SelectedIndex, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Height="20">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                                    RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

The ViewModel

```
class ExpenseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
        {
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    private void populate()
    {
        _totalPeople.Add(2);
        _totalPeople.Add(3);
        _totalPeople.Add(4);
        _totalPeople.Add(5);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalPeople");
    }
    private List<int> _totalPeople;
    public IEnumerable<int> TotalPeople
    {
        get { return _totalPeople; }
    }

    public ExpenseViewModel()
    {
        _totalPeople = new List<int>();
        populate();
    }

    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

    private string _error;
    public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName.Equals("SelectedIndex"))
            {
               if(SelectedIndex==0)
               {
                   _error = "Please Select One";
               }
            }
            return Error;
        }
    }
}
```